# Print only those lines of a file with unique first column and specific third column value

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like below

```
1,1230,add
1,1235,remove
2,1240,add
2,1245,remove
3,1250,add
4,1255,remove
```

I want to print those lines which have a unique value for the first field, *and* where the 3rd field is equal to `add`. The expected output for the example would be

```
3,1250,add
```

or only the first column, i.e.

```
3
```

The below command give me distinct records, but later I want to check if 3rd column is "add" then only print the output.

```
awk -F ',' 'print $1' filename | uniq -u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, a double-pass approach comes to mind:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{seen[$1]++;next} $3=="add" && seen[$1]==1' file.txt file.txt
```

This will process the input file twice (hence it is stated two times as argument).

- In the first pass, where `NR` , the global line counter, is equal to `FNR`, the per-file line-counter, we only count how often this particular value of the first field is encountered, but otherwise skip processing immediately (the `next` statement).
- In the second pass, we check if the third field equals `add`, and that the first field has only occured once. If so, we print the line (because these two conditions will evaluate to `true`).

Answer (score 0):

Since AdminBee already showed the `awk`-way, here's another approach with standard utils:

```
 sort -t',' -k1,1 file | uniq -u -w 1 | grep 'add$'
```

- `sort` using comma as separator and sorting by field 1 only
- `uniq` printing only unique lines but checking no more than 1 (**!**) character per line
- now `grep` lines ending in "add"

Limitation: `uniq` of course only checks one character. For two- or more-digit entries in field 1, one would have to preprocess field 1 e.g. with zero-padding on the left and then increase the number of characters for the check accordingly. Sorting may be skipped if your file is already sorted as given in your example.

Comment: @ricky Distinct? So you want lines where the first field is unique (i.e. appears *only once*) in the file and last  field is add?

Comment: @Fiximan, Correct

Answer (score 0):

in one go with awk :

```
awk -F ',' '  
  { if ( ! seen[$1]++ )
    { if ( $3 == "add" )
        keep[$1] = $0
    }
    else
    {
      if ( keep[$1] )
        delete keep[$1]
    }
  }
  END  {
    for (i in keep)
      print keep[i]
  }'  infile
```